# PHP Class not found while it's included

Tags: php, class, static-members

I have a problem with classes which cannot be found in PHP.

The first thing I do is 'require_once' a file which 'require_once's all other files. When loading, no problems are showed. But when I start calling my function (Users::verificate();) I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Users' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sparks/dashboard.php on line 4
```

To test I've added a simple class with a function which only outputs a string with the echo method. This works so the problem has to be with this class. A MySql function which I call like this just works.

```
$mySql = new MySql();
$mySql->executeQuery('...');
```

The simple class has static a static function which I call like this (Oh, this works):

```
simple::launch();
```

In the Users class I'm calling non static functions from the MySql class from a static function. Can this be the problem?

Like another question here on SO suggested the problem isn't in using short php opening tags instead of the traditional php opening tag.

Even a little hint may help me :). Thanks for your time!

**Edit:**
I've added some relevant code from the User class. This is basically what it all looks like:

```
<?php
class Users {
    public static function authenticate($email, $password) {
        $mySql = new MySql();

        $mySqlResult = $mySql->executeQuery("selectUser", [$email]);

        ...
    }

    public static function isAdmin() {
        if ($_SESSION['isAdmin']) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Edit 2:**
I'm trying to show the flow:
From dashboard.php this are the first code lines:

```
<?php
    require_once('code/init.php');
    simple::launch();
    if (!Users::verify()) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

simple::launch(); is the code I used to test. This executes well. From this on the init.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('simple.php');
require_once('MySql.php');
require_once('Users.php');
require_once('Projects.php');
```

The file names are correct as I get a visible error when these are wrong.

dashboard.php exists in the root. From there is a folder called 'code' which contains all these files.

Comment: can you post the relevant code from this User class?

Comment: Also, just a pet peeve, but 'verificate' isn't a word.  You're looking for 'verify'.

Comment: @Stoic: Code added :)

Comment: You should edit your question to show the following: Where you're including the file that includes everything else, that include file, and where/how you're trying to access that class.  It's obviously a scope/visibility problem, but it's difficult to pinpoint a solution without being able to follow the execution flow.

Comment: @KevinM1: Just a little 'beauty' issue... But thanks for the hint :) I'll edit it c:

Comment: Can you show us dashboard.php require_once line?

Comment: @KevinM1 & andylibrian More relevant code is added. :)

Comment: @andylibrian More relevant code is added :)

Comment: Use get_required_files() function just a line before you create object from Users class.Maybe helpful .

Comment: @MbRostami turned out that users.php was included from the root path while the init file existed in the code folder. All other files were included from the code folder for some strange reason... Thanks for the helpful hint however!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MbRostami gave the advice in a comment to use the 'get_required_files()' function to see which files are included. It turns out that the wrong files were loaded.

```
Root
| dashboard.php
| users.php
|- code
 | Users.php
 | init.php
```

In the init.php file the Users.php file (both files are in the code folder) was required. But for some reason the users.php file from the root was loaded. Some strange behaviour imho. Ahwell, that's something to investigate during the christmas days.

Problem is solved! Thanks!